# Prevent security risks from html inspectors?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I was recently messing with a django local server project and I had a input like

```
<form....{% csrf_token %}
....
<input type="text" value="foo" readonly />
....
</form>
```

Now the value of the input should stay the way I want it to ("foo"), but I used google chrome inspect and was able to change the value of the readonly input and pass the new value to the server, which saved the bad value.

So I have a few questions:

1. What are the general rules or mental checklists to prevent security risks like this?
2. <strike>Could I use the JavaScript console and corrupt data like this as well?</strike> Update: YEP.
3. So do I have to basically do all my checks on the server side?
4. If no to 3, what are the client side validations that are protected from html/js inspectors?

Edit:

I'm guessing from the answers so far, it's yes to 3.  So should I still bother with client side security/checks?  Will they actually make me more secure or is it just a false sense of security (which is bad)? Should I do client side checks to possibly save some checks on the server side, so my performance might be better?  **Basically: How much client side checking should I do?**

Comment: Never trust the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself why you needed that readonly value in the first place. Presumably, it was your code that generated it, when the user first requested the form. So, what was available to your code when the user requested the form that is not available when the user submits it back? There shouldn't be anything, which should lead you to the conclusion that that field can just as easily be generated on submit, without it needing to appear in the form at all.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reply on Javascript or anything on the client side for security. Just ensure that your server is secure.

For example you can just telnet to the port and send the appropriate data to the server. This will thwart and checks via Javascript (or any other technology( on the client side.

Just use Javascript to make the users experience on the client more enjoyable and more responsive. Do not use it for security.

Answer (score 1):

Your server code must be the final authority, it simply cannot rely on the quality of validation that the client has done. View all clients, be they HTML or otherwise as prone to the effects of both devious users and fallible coders.

Comment: The -1 by whoever was unfair - I have rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Never believe the data sent by a user (cookies, session,parameters in HTTP request,...). All data send by users can be modified.
2. Yes of course
3. It is still to be done.